# Get LTE parameters of signal strength

Tags: android, parameters, lte

I am developing an application to get some LTE parameters like RSSI,RSRQ,RSRP, CQI. I know the classes(API 17 or higher) that I have to use, but I dont how to use it. If someone can show me a complete example I'll be very grateful to him. I need these parameters for my degree project.Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi user3305388, welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please, can you be more specific about the problem?  Which classes are you going to use, and what exactly is stopping you from using them?

Comment: Hi! I want to use the class signalstrength to get rsrq,rssi,rsrp...If it is possible, otherwise, I will use any other class that you suggest.Thank in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the **Advanced Signal Status** app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cc.signalinfo and its GitHub repository https://github.com/yareally/SignalInfo It works fine.